# Getting a single value from MySQL on Django (Python)

Tags: python, django

I could get a single value from MySQL database on Django(Python). However, it looks like the code are too long. Is there a way to make it short codes? Thanks

```
    result = cursor.execute("SELECT idx FROM myapp_profile WHERE full_name = '"+fullname+"' AND birthday = '"+birthday+"' LIMIT 1")
    if result:
        #create session
        col_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
        while True:
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row is None:
                break
            resultsList = dict(izip(col_names, row))

        profile_idx = resultsList["idx"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the combination of the [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) and the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) methods:

```
profile = Profile.objects.only('idx').filter(full_name=full_name,
                                             birthday=birthday).first()
profile_idx = profile.idx if profile else None
```

Another solution is to use the [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
indexes = list(Profile.objects.filter(full_name=full_name, birthday=birthday) 
                              .values_list('idx', flat=True)[:1])
profile_idx = indexes[0] if indexes else None
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what your exactly trying to do for instance if your just looking for people with birthdays today or if your lookimg for someones birthday. That make sence? So if your just looking for people with todays bday you should create a variable with todays date amd look for the user with that date. I guess what im asking is what are youyou trying to do because that will depend on query magic you would use.